# How do I install telepresence version 1 in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

I am trying to install telepresence version 1 in ubuntu 22.04 but I don't have the download links to it.

Answer (score 1):

Telepresence version 1 is no longer supported but you can install the new version [here](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/telepresence/latest/install). Feel free also to join the [Telepresence open source slack channel](https://a8r.io/slack) if you have further questions or want to join our weekly help session for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I grabbed a version of telepresence that was published for 20.04 and it seems to work for me. Here are the details of what I did:

```
# install telepresence pre-requisites
apt install torsocks sshfs conntrack
# HACK - download the version of telepresence for Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)
curl -L https://packagecloud.io/datawireio/telepresence/packages/ubuntu/focal/telepresence_0.109_amd64.deb/download.deb?distro_version_id=210 -o telepresence_0.109_amd64.deb
# install telepresence
dpkg -i telepresence_0.109_amd64.deb
```